# Как правильно изменить путь к папке в jQuery File Upload?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fileupload

Всем привет!

Столкнулся со следующей задачей: 
Имеется проект, в котором есть несколько динамических страниц, т.е. их содержимое меняется в зависимости от GET-параметра в адресной строке. 
На каждой странице работает плагин `jQuery File Upload`.

Если загружать файлы с его помощью на страницу, плагин создает новую папку с именем GET-параметра (пусть это будет `hash`). И загружает эти файлы только туда. 
Соответственно и уже загруженные файлы он должен отображать только из этой папки.

Структура файлов такая:

```
images/
fileupload/
index.php
```

Разобрался, что пути редактируются в `UploadHandler.php`
Сейчас они выглядят так:

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'../../../../images/' . $_SESSION['hash'] . '/',

'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'../../../../images/' . $_SESSION['hash'] . '/',
```

Здесь `$_SESSION['hash']` - это название папки, которое захватывается на странице с GET-параметром и передается в сессию при загрузке.

Работает корректно, но только на локальном сервере. Да и по сути своей понимаю, что написана ерунда, пусть выглядит некорректно при просмотре через панель разработчика.

Если не менять путь и оставить стандартный путь к `/files/` внутри плагина, все также работает, но тогда страницы не отображают содержимое папки с картинками.

Как эту проблему можно правильно решить?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно сказать, замучился я настраивать jQuery File Upload под свои нужды.
Тяжел он и много зависимостей.

Поэтому нашел другое решение, более простое и гибкое: 
[DropZone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Надеюсь, что кто-то прочитает этот ответ раньше, чем начнет копаться и тратить массу времени на разбор File Upload-а.